# Cannot access sinatra app on AWS Windows from remote machine

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra app running on an AWS windows instance. Running the application from the localhost works fine (i.e. `http://localhost:4567`), but I am unable to run it remotely.

My AWS windows instance is available to me from remote as I am able to connect to it using RDP.

After reading some other similar issues, I have already applied the following:

1. My AWS security group is opened for port 4567 (I actually also opened it for any inbound connection just to see if that will solve the issue - it didn't)
2. I tried running: `ruby my_sinatra_app.rb -o 0.0.0.0`
3. I tried running: `ruby my_sinatra_app.rb -e production`
4. I tried adding to the application itself the following code: `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'`

I am still unable to run the application remotely. Any idea?

Comment: why you don't use rakeup and a config.ru file? Not sure if this can solve your problem but it's better to deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue, so for the sake of completeness I am publishing the answer.

This wasn't a Sinatra issue, but an AWS issue (maybe not really an issue, more like my misunderstanding). I was under the impression that updating the AWS security group for opening the 4567 port will do the trick.

However, it turns out that I needed also to open the port on the Windows Firewall on my Windows AWS instance. After opening the port on the Windows Firewall I was able to remotely connect to my Sinatra app.